# Pass a unique reference of a clicked element via AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

The title is somewhat confusing, I'm not sure how to word it right as a title.

I'll try to explain better:
I have a forum page, of course as in every other forum elsewhere you can comment on posts. Being able to delete what you wrote is something I should include.

To do this I was planning on setting up a separate page that deletes the comment and using AJAX to do it seamlessly. However, I would need the specific reply ID to delete the one the user is intending to delete.

Below is a link to a picture. The picture demonstrates several comments being posted, obviously they all have separate id's in the database, I'm just not sure how to get the proper one.

[image: Picture of a post with comments]

So by only a click I need to retrieve the reply ID, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a `hidden` input with the id of the post to every post and send that along the AJAX call. Then server side check if that post id belongs to the user etc etc.

Comment: @GillBates awesome, thank you :)

Comment: @GillBates Please only use comments to seek clarification.  Submit answers as answers; this is how SO is designed to work.

Comment: @Saetre when user clicks on delete button it must delete the post via `AJAX` right

Comment: @mickmackusa No, it's not. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments . In this case, I didn't want to write a full answer because a hidden input is quite old and there's probably better ways nowadays.

Comment: @mickmackusa you see the irony in your comment, right?

Comment: @MacroMan are you seeking clarification? (I'm just seeking clarification.)

Comment: @GillBates That is not a rules page that you linked, that is an opinion page.  If you have a look at the grey placeholder text on any of the comment boxes on SO, you will read "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements."  I will thank you for sending me to Meta, I've been wanting to have a look around over there.  Here is another Meta link I'd like you to read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230676/352329  Please do not read any negative tone here; I am merely asking you to make a small adjustment to where you post your contributions.

Comment: @MacroMan Sure, there is irony in what I said, so let me clarify.  The comment box placeholder says: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements."  I was actually asking for Gill to make an improvement in his posting location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add data-id="XXX" to element. and access through the class

```
$('.yourClass').click(function(event) {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   console.log(id);
});
```

Check in your browser console you got the ID

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you just explained, you can attach an attribute to your comment while adding it in the first place like

`<div class="single-comment">
   <a data-reply-id='23'>Click me, I am a comment!</a>
</div>`

This will allow you to reference the data-id using ajax to get back its value and then POST it.

Does that make sense a bit?

I do think Martin Kuchyňár is saying the same.